# Minecraft Premium: "Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When i try to log in to my minecraft premium account it says:

> Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers. Please make sure that you are online, and that Minecraft is not blocked.

I tried turning off the firewall and updating Java (64-bit) but it still doesn't working. I'm using Wi-Fi. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Wifi in a place that would restrict access, such as a school or something?

Comment: No, i'm using my home private WiFi network .