# How do I get Minecraft to connect to the servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I was trying to log into Minecraft one day and I was greeted with this:

```
Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers.
```

I went to [help.mojang.com](http://help.mojang.com/) to see the server statuses. They all looked okay.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If this has only happened once then there just might be a problem with their servers, which is generally temporary.

Comment: I went to help.mojang.com to see the server statuses. They all looked okay.

Comment: I would recommend adding that information to the question itself. Alongside that you should add anything else you have tried, if you logged into the launcher or elsewhere, or any other information that might help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Good idea, although I don't think I did too much to cause this.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of Minecraft (1.10.2) or some other version?

Comment: I can't even set my version.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by platform? Do you mean the version I am using of Minecraft or my computer?

Comment: I had meant if you were on PC, xbox, or mobile, but I realize now you've already implied that previously. Another option seems to be with messing with your antivirus. Try checking if minecraft is allowed there, disable the antivirus temporarily, and possibly (one person using avg reported this worked) uninstall it entirely for a bit.

Comment: Also try running the launcher as administrator

Comment: None of those suggestions worked, unfortunately. I think using a premium account is what caused this.

Comment: The closest I've found to your question with regards to premium accounts was [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201780/minecraft-premium-sorry-but-we-couldnt-connect-to-our-servers?noredirect=1&lq=1). That question was unanswered and marked as a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163800/cannot-launch-minecraft-certificatenotyetvalidexception). I would recommend checking out the second link and seeing if it applies. If that still doesn't work, check if there's any error messages after the 'Sorry cant connect' message and add that.

Comment: Do you think using a different launcher would work? Such as the [Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262884-launcher-magic-launcher-1-3-4-mods-options)?

Answer (score 1):

According to a few users on [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/archive/mojang-account-minecraft-net/1943446-sorry-but-we-couldnt-connect-to-our-servers) forum post that were experiencing the same problem, one possible solution is to simply update Java and try again.

If that doesn't work try checking your firewall settings to see if Minecraft or Java is being blocked.

Comment: I tried what you said. Java was up-to-date, and Minecraft nor Java was blocked by firewall. I would like to mention I tried using a premium account.